# Shell scripting, finding average of loop results

Tags: linux, shell, for-loop

I made a loop to find the results of calculating each number from (1 to 10 mod 5) + 2

```
for (( i = 0; i <= 10; i++))
do 
    calculate=$(( i % 5 + 2 ))
    echo "($i % 5) + 2 = " $calculate
done
average=$(($calculate/10))
echo $average`
```

My problem is fixing my code so that I can take all the results of the loop and find the average of them
Its returning back 0 for the average

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep a full total - `($calculate/10)` is just the *last* iteration. Keep a running total initialized to zero before the loop `total = 0` ... then add the calculated value to the total in each iteration of the loop `total = $( $total + $calculate )` Then the average is `total/10` (not calculate/10).

```
#!/bin/bash
total=0
for (( i = 0; i <= 10; i++))
do 
    calculate=$(( i % 5 + 2 ))
    total=$(( $total + $calculate ))
    echo "($i % 5) + 2 = " $calculate
done
#average=$(($calculate/10))
average=$(($total/10))
echo $average
```